# Returning an object from a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, callback, npm-request

I want to return an object out of a callback. When I run the below code, the log of the `body` object looks as expected. It appears to be the correct JSON object containing the response I want from the server: name, email, website, etc.

But the `result` object appears to contain information about the request itself instead of the response object.

How do I return the `body` object so that I can access it from the `result` variable?

```js
const request = require('request'); // npm i request -s

module.exports = async config => {
  ...

  const result = await request.get( url, options,
    ( error, response, body, ) => {
      console.log( 'body', body, ); // I want the other log to look like this log.
      return body;
    }
  );

  console.log( 'result', result, ); // I want this log to look like the above log.
  // In other words, I want the below line to be the name, email, website JSON object
  // contained in the body
  return result;
}
```

This is what I want from `result`.

console.log( 'body', body, );

```
body {
  "name": "foo",
  "email": "foo@example.com",
  "website": "www.example.com",
  ...
}
```

This is what I actually get from `result`.

console.log( 'result', result, );

```
result Request {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    error: [Function: bound ],
    complete: [Function: bound ],
    pipe: [Function]
  },
  _eventsCount: 3,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  uri: Url {
    protocol: 'https:',
    slashes: true,
    auth: null,
    host: 'api.example.com',
    port: 443,
    hostname: 'api.example.com',
    hash: null,
  },
  callback: [Function],
  method: 'GET',
  readable: true,
  writable: true,
  explicitMethod: true,
  _qs: Querystring {
    request: [Circular],
    lib: { formats: [Object], parse: [Function], stringify: [Function] },
    useQuerystring: undefined,
    parseOptions: {},
    stringifyOptions: {}
  },
  _auth: Auth {
    request: [Circular],
```

Comment: it's because you have the return statement inside the `request.get` callback. Because you named the constant request variable as the `request.get` method, it will always be an instance of that method unless you change it to a `let` or `var` and declare it as something else inside the request callback.

Comment: They're are different kind of objects, please read this: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/whats-difference-between-javascript-object-json-kishorkumar-bachhav

Comment: @E2017: What would be an example of how I would implement your answer explicitly in code? Could you please provide an example?

Comment: From the docs it looks like requiring `[request-promise-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#promises--asyncawait)  ` may be what you're looking for.

Comment: [npm package request-promise-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise-native)